# Tokens SDK: Problems with Confidential Tokens and Observers

Tags: corda

**Setup:**

- Corda: 4.6
- Tokens SDK: 1.2.2

**Problem:**

When issuing/moving Confidential Fungible and Non-Fungible tokens using Flows:

- ConfidentialIssueTokens()
- ConfidentialMoveFungibleTokens()
- ConfidentialMoveNonFungibleTokens()

If an Observer is included an error will occur.

When testing with a MockNetwork the following error is reported:

> [ERROR] 13:45:18 [Mock network] SqlExceptionHelper. - NULL not allowed
> for column "HOLDER"; SQL statement: insert into non_fungible_token
> (holder, issuer, token_class, token_identifier, output_index,
> transaction_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23502-199]

When running nodes locally using Cordform the following error appears in the Observer's log:

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
> NULL not allowed for column "HOLDER"; SQL statement: insert into
> fungible_token (amount, holder, issuer, holding_key, token_class,
> token_identifier, output_index, transaction_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
> ?, ?, ?) [23502-199]

The Observer will not receive the state and a Flow will be entered in their Flow Hospital.  Otherwise the transaction seems to be successful.  The tokens will be successfully issued/moved to the appropriate Party's vaults.

Comment: Never used the Confidential** methods, I have to be honest. Try to check out the unit tests in the Token SDK to see if there's something you can spot: https://github1s.com/corda/token-sdk/blob/HEAD/workflows/src/test/kotlin/com/r3/corda/lib/tokens/workflows/MoveTokensTest.kt?q=ConfidentialMoveFungibleTokens#L141

Comment: this looks like it should be a github issue, I'll share internally, thanks!